# Get values from comma separated string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 - unfortunately `STRING_SPLIT` function is not implemented in this version.

My problem is this: I have a string `@cRECE_STA = 'A,B,C'` - would like to get values from that string like:

```
+------+
| Col1 |
+------+
| A    |
| B    |
| C    |
+------+
```

I need this because those values will be later inserted into table, one by one. How to do this?

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: [DelimitedSplit8k_lead](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just chars in the string you can use

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(45) = 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I';

WITH LN(IDX) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT IDX + 1
  FROM LN
  WHERE IDX <= LEN(@Str)
)
,
Str(ID, V) AS
(
  SELECT 1, @Str
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(V, IDX, ID) Results
FROM Str CROSS JOIN LN
WHERE IDX % 2 = 1;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6d4ca2462cf3da87e932f6190b93762)**

If not, you need to create your own **[`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)** function.